Two Tabs with same name occurs; one with previous coding?
In the last month or so I've found that there are completely unpredictable times when the following will happen...
After a 'live' debugging session finishes (meaning a debugging round that took place while the app was running), I'll close the app and return to Visual Studio 2022 in order to continue coding. I'll look up at VS' file tabs and I'm surprised to see that there's suddenly two tabs that display the same file name.  Even worse, one of the tab's window consists of code from an older version of that file (perhaps the version that was last saved in a previous programming session). Even worse than that, VS has automatically (unbeknownst to me) focused on the code in this mysterious (now obsolete) file.
If I haven't noticed that there are now two tabs with the same file name, I just continue typing; not knowing that I'm suddenly revising an old/obsolete file.
As you can perhaps imagine, the next day, when I open VS to continue to work on that Solution, I find that I've lost at least some of my changes from my previous session; in retrospect probably because at some point during the previous programming session I had unknowingly started revising the wrong older/obsolete version of the file.
Has anyone else experienced this?  If so, I would sure appreciate some feedback because I'm losing whole chunks of programming revisions and time when this happens.  And I can't imagine that the remedy I'm going to always have to live with is that I must check the VS tabs whenever I close a 'live' debugging round.
Again, this began, at most, a couple of months ago.  In all my many years of using VS, I never experienced this prior to that.  If it helps you to know this, my current version of VS 2022 is 17.10.3

Not the same, but strange behaviour on recovery files created when I've saved files in debug mode.  VS has become more and more cantankerous over the last year or so, this being just one example.  I've been wondering about a fully blown re-install of late to fix my install's many foibles!  I've just closed a session down because it decided to go not full screen, and simply wouldn't return to full screen.

When you have multiple windows with the same file, does any of them show a lock in the tab header?

Good question PMF.  For what it's worth, I seldom (if ever) lock a tab header; at least not deliberately.  That said, I may sometimes do that unintentionally.  The next time this issue crops up for me, I'll certainly check out which tabs are locked; if any.

Yes, I've experienced similar behaviour in exactly the time frame you cite. It is extremely disruptive and unhelpful. I wasn't able to reliably reproduce it or spot a pattern, although there seemed to be a link with having switched branches in source control. I had no better approach than just closing and re-opening the solution (which I have to do regularly anyway because VS crashes at least 50% of the time when I open NuGet Package Manager). I don't recall seeing the issue for perhaps three weeks, though, so perhaps it has gone away (i.e. been fixed in an update).

Thanks Neil T.  Just so you know, at least on my end, I don't think the problem is related to branching.  I'm currently in a phase of coding that hasn't seemed to require much branching.  Ironically though, given my current issue, perhaps I should start doing more branching!

This issue just cropped up again for me!  If this is a clue for anyone, when the old/obsolete file showed up, it's tab had defaulted to 'locked'.  (If it helps to know this, none of my other tabs were locked at that time; including the tab that held inside it the actual file I was trying to work on.  Thanks PMF for telling me to look for this.  That said, this still remains a big issue for me, so any further help would be much appreciated.

Update: Fwiw, my further research indicates that this issue seems to be a VS issue that goes back years.  I've also notified Syncfusion of this issue because it occurred to me later that I started experiencing the issue after I started implementing a few of their products.  Important: This does not prove that Syncfusion is at issue.  I'm generally quite happy with their products and their very good support.  I just thought the coincidence was worth mentioning to them.  We'll see.
